# Visualizing histograms

Tags: rust, grafana, open-telemetry

I've been using mainly CloudWatch and some in-house systems before for monitoring and I'm trying to setup Opentelemetry metrics with Grafana for local testing. The code that I have is currently the following:

```
histogram.record(latency, &[KeyValue::new("shard", self.shard_id)]);
```

Here `histogram` is just an instance of this:

https://docs.rs/opentelemetry/latest/opentelemetry/metrics/struct.Histogram.html

What I now see in Grafana if I try to create a visualization are the variables:

```
latency_bucket
latency_count
latency_sum
```

What is the proper visualization for these in Grafana and what's the query? For instance, `latency_bucket` has the labels `le` (this looks like the buckets) and `shard`, i.e. the label that I'm attaching myself.

The following question seems relevant, but doesn't provide an answer:

[Using a Grafana Histogram with Prometheus Buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74740726/using-a-grafana-histogram-with-prometheus-buckets)

Are these kinds of metrics not easily usable in Grafana?